# Change ripple effect duration in MUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to modify ripple effect duration in theme file

I've tried things like

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    props: {
        MuiButtonBase: {
            TouchRippleProps: {
                animationDuration: '5s',
                transitionDuration: '5s',
            },
            classes: {
                root: 'CustomizeTouchRipple'
            }
        },
    }
})
```

Not working.. but class is added

Edit:

I found its a constant in `TouchRipple` component
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/c06a88d24235685dd769c1a3df82152ded17a6ca/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js#L8

Comment: What version of MUI do you use, 4 or 5?

Comment: i'm using version 4, 
TouchRipple component contain const DURATION = 550

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/5c79f3d80573c3f8627ed3ef7b12b35e7615438e/packages/mui-material-next/src/Button/TouchRipple.js#L74), the class name where the `animationDuration` is set is `MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible`. You just need to override that value:

**V5**

```
<Button
  sx={{
    '&& .MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible': {
      animationDuration: '200ms',
    },
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

```
const theme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        '& .MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible': {
          animationDuration: '200ms',
        },
      },
    },
    // if you want to change the ripple duration of all components that have ripple
    // effect (e.g. Button, CardActionArea, FAB...)
    MuiTouchRipple: {
      rippleVisible: {
        animationDuration: '200ms',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks, it worked very well
also if we want to make it more global (FAB,...etc) we can use  MuiButtonBase instead of MuiButton

Comment: I don't recall seeing anything other than `ButtonBase` uses `TouchRipple` directly so setting the ripple duration in `ButtonBase` should also do the trick. @MahmoudHassan